# Варианты передачи\получения JSON-телеграммы

Tags: c#, json

Мой объект (класс) отображается в браузере как содержимое страницы. Что предпринять, чтоб браузер предлагал скачать текстовый файл, в котором и было содержимое моего объекта?

```
    DataContractJsonSerializer jsonFormatter = new                 
    DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(IndexBPC));
    jsonFormatter.WriteObject(memStream, jsonResp);

    HttpClient.JsonArr = memStream.ToArray();//из потока помещаю в массив байт
    response.ContentLength64 = HttpClient.JsonArr.Length;// получаем поток ответа
    Stream output = response.OutputStream;// пишем в него ответ
    output.Write(HttpClient.JsonArr, 0, HttpClient.JsonArr.Length);
```

Варианты с использованием WebInvoke пока не рассматриваю.